# Passing Multiple Values into Generator in Python

Tags: python, arguments, generator

I am wondering if it is possible to pass several values into a generator in Python. I found an example where one is passed:

```
def counter(maximum):
    i = 0
    while i < maximum:
        val = (yield i)
        # If value provided, change counter
        if val is not None:
            i = val
        else:
            i += 1
```

Executing the above function:

```
>>> it = counter(10)  
>>> next(it)  
0
>>> next(it)  
1
>>> it.send(8)  
8
>>> next(it)  
9
>>> next(it)  
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "t.py", line 15, in <module>
    it.next()
StopIteration
```

The question is two-fold.

The first is how does the `counter` function know about the variable `val`? It does not seem to be defined or passed anywhere. Is there a convention that forces us to use this name in case we would like to pass a value to a generator?

The second question is how can we pass multiple values into a generator? Can this be done in a single `send()` call or are multiple calls required?

Answer (score 2):

First answer: `val` is a totally arbitrary name, you can use any valid python identifier here. `counter` "knows" about it because it explicitely binds it to the value of the `(yield i)` expression, which will be `None` if nothing was sent (plain `next(it)` call) or whatever was passed to `it.send()`.

Second: `send()` takes a single value, but nothing prevents you from passing a `tuple` or `list` (as long as your generator handles it correctly of course).

Edit: answering to your other questions in the comments

> Would not the val always be not None except for the last iteration of the loop?

Why ??? the execution of `yield <whatever>` is triggered either by normal iteration over the generator and by an explicit call to `generator.send(something)`. In the first case, the value of the `yield whatever` "expression" (well technically `yield` is a statement but since it can "produce" a value it behaves like an expression here) is `None`.  In the second case it's whatever has been passed to `.send()`.

This has nothing to do with the number of iterations or an inner loop (that may just not exist - you don't have to have an inner loop in a generator).

> That is, does the generator "freeze" exactly upon encountering the yield

It suspends its execution on the `yield` statement, and resume on the next iteration or `.send()` call:

```
>>> def gen(x):
...     for i in xrange(x):
...         print "before yield" 
...         wot = (yield x)
...         print "after yield - wot is '%s'" % wot
...         if wot is not None:
...             x = wot
...             print "x is now %s" % x
... 
>>> g = gen(5)
>>> next(g)
before yield
5
>>> next(g)
after yield - wot is 'None'
before yield
5
>>> g.send(10)
after yield - wot is '10'
x is now 10
before yield
10
>>> next(g)
after yield - wot is 'None'
before yield
10
```

> or does it actually go through the conditional, decide upon what the i should be, yield it and then suspend the execution until another next() is invoked?

Answer above - which you could have found out by yourself actually ;)

Comment: I see. Would not the `val` always be `not None` except for the last iteration of the loop? That is, does the generator "freeze" exactly upon encountering the `yield` or does it actually go through the conditional, decide upon what the `i` should be, yield it and then suspend the execution until another `next()` is invoked?